# Python Pretty table

Tags: python

```
List1 = [('100.20.300.400', 'varagu', 'success'), ('100.20.300.500', 'thinai', 'success')]
List2 = [('100.20.300.600', 'Ragi', 'Failed')]



 table = PrettyTable(['IP', 'Name', 'Result'])
for IP, Name, Result in succeed_ip.__getitem__():
    table.add_row([IP, Name, Result])
print table

Error: for IP, Name, Result in succeed_ip.__getitem__():
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

> I am getting the result as expected, i am mentioning the indexes
>   separately to display in the table. Instead of mentioning the List1
>   indexes, can i get the same result. I tried the option 
>   table.add_row(List1), but i didnt get the result.I am planning to
>   include more Lists in future, so i dont want to mention the indexes
>   every time. Please help. Thanks !!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to avoid below format, means without mentioning indexes, i need the same result                                                                                                                         table.add_row(List1[0])
table.add_row(List1[1])

Comment: Use a for-loop.

Comment: i tried, i got below error message:                                                                                           for IP, Name, Result in succeed_ip.__getitem__():
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List1 = [('100.20.300.400', 'varagu', 'success'), ('100.20.300.500', 'thinai', 'success')]
List2 = [('100.20.300.600', 'Ragi', 'Failed')]

table = PrettyTable(['IP', 'Name', 'Result'])
for IP, Name, Result in List1:
    table.add_row([IP, Name, Result])
print table

ftable = PrettyTable(['IP', 'Name', 'Result'])
for IP, Name, Result in List2:
    ftable.add_row([IP, Name, Result])
print ftable

Above script gave me the result for me. Issue is resolved. Thanks for the support.
```